# PHP header("Location: ..") not working with axios correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, axios, compression

I'm encountering an issue with PHP headers (header("Location: ...")) in conjunction with an HTML form and Axios. The problem arises when using Axios to post form data. In my PHP script, I have an if condition to check if the form inputs are empty. When my upload button has the type set to "button" and I fill all the inputs, everything works smoothly, and the data is successfully stored in the database.

However, when I leave one or more inputs empty, nothing is inserted into the database, and the URL doesn't change to 'index.php?empty' as expected. Strangely, when the button type is changed to "submit" and I select an image without filling the text input, the URL changes correctly to 'index.php?empty'. Yet, if I fill the text input without selecting an image, the URL changes to 'direct.php', and only the text data gets stored in the database, excluding the image.

It seems that the PHP header("Location: ...") is not working as expected in this scenario. Any suggestions or solutions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your time.
(Note that i'm using two libraries axios and compressorjs)

```
<body>
    <form action="direct.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="mainimg">
            <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="file" onchange="compressImg()">
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            <input type="text" name="test">
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="uploadData()">Upload</button>
    </form>

    <script src="compressorjs-main/dist/compressor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.6.3/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let formData; 

        function compressImg() {
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
            const file = fileInput.files[0];

            if (!file) {
                return;
            }

            new Compressor(file, {
                quality: 0.6,
                maxWidth: 700,
                maxHeight: 700,
                success(result) {
                    formData = new FormData();
                    console.log('Original Size:', file.size);
                    console.log('Compressed Size:', result.size);
                    console.log("Image name after compression", result.name);

                    formData.delete('file');
                    formData.append('file', result, result.name);
                },
                error(err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                },
            });
        }

        function uploadData() {

            if (formData) {

                formData.append('test', document.querySelector('[name="test"]').value);


                axios.post('direct.php', formData).then(() => {
                    console.log('Upload success');
                    console.log(formData);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('No data to upload');
            }
        }
```

```
    $compressedImage = $_FILES['file'];
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    if(empty($compressedImage) || empty($test)){
        header("Location: index.php?empty");
    } else {
        echo "Original File Name: " . $compressedImage['name'] . "<br>";
        echo "Original File Size: " . $compressedImage['size'] . "<br>";

        $targetDir = 'image/';
        $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($compressedImage['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($compressedImage['tmp_name'], $targetFile);

        echo "Moved File Name: " . $compressedImage['name'] . "<br>";
        echo "Moved File Size: " . filesize($targetFile) . "<br>";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO account (pic, test) VALUES (?, ?)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        // Update the bind_param line to include both placeholders
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $targetFile, $test);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        $conn->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> the URL doesn't change to 'index.php?empty' as expected

...no, that's not expected. Asynchronous AJAX requests (which is what your Axios is doing) don't automatically read server-side Location headers and make the request to the specified URL. Whereas if you make a non-AJAX request (such as by submitting a form or clicking a link) then the browser will automatically follow any Location header in the response.

So why doesn't the Axios/AJAX request follow the link automatically? That's because such requests are designed to be asynchronous and run in the background, giving programmers the ability to keep the browser on the same page, while still communicating with the server. (Before AJAX was invented, every request to the server had to involve a full refresh of the page, which often led to a poorer user experience, and/or a more complicated codebase to handle certain functionality).

The simple solution, if you want to navigate the user to a new URL in certain circumstances following such an asynchronous request, is to do it in JavaScript, in the callback which runs after the asynchronous request has completed.

In your case, you need PHP to indicate to the client-side that the validation failed, so it can take appropriate action. Therefore you could write something like:

```
if(empty($compressedImage) || empty($test)){
    echo "0";
}
```

And then in the JavaScript:

```
axios.post('direct.php', formData).then((response) => {
    if (response == "0") {
      window.location.href = "index.php?empty";
    }
    else {
      console.log('Upload success');
      console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: I wrote the same if condition for PHP validation `if(empty($compressedImage) || empty($test)){
    echo "0";
}` and nothing happened when i leave the inputs empty (0 which i expect)
I need to make a validation also in PHP for security purposes.

Comment: So did you debug it? It should work. What do you see in the network tool, or the console, or using the JS debugger? Whereabouts does the code deviate from what it's supposed to do?

Comment: The code behavior is, when i select an image without fill the input all worked as expected and the URL changes to index.php?empty, but when i fill the input without selecting an image nothing happens, and when i dont select an image or fill the input also nothing happens.

Comment: (i changed the `if (response == "0") {`  to  `if (response.data == "0") {`)

Comment: So did that change work?

Comment: P.s. `nothing happens` is almost never the case. Usually if you don't see anything then it simply means you haven't looked hard enough, i.e. by using the right tools to observe the code - line by line if necessary. Hence why I suggested using those developer tools to investigate things, like checking exactly what is returned by the php, and so on